# Forward journald Logs on CentOS7 to SIEM-Server

Tags: centos, rsyslog, systemd-journald

Is it possible to directly forward logs from `journald` to a Remote-Log-Server? I only see the option `ForwardToSyslog` in the `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` config file.

Or do I have to forward it to `syslogd` and then configure `rsyslog`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Journald does not allow for TCP forwarding as far as I know. You would indeed have to duplicate its messages to syslog.

Answer (score 0):

This feature had been [requested](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/7170), the official recommendation is to use [netlogd](https://github.com/systemd/systemd-netlogd) for that, which will take care of border cases like network going up/down.